# Is it better to have temporary tables or have records in tables with a temp state for a cart purchase?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to create a cart purchase data model.  There are various things a user can purchase such as credit and products (each will have a separate set of attributes). On successful completion of a transaction, each item purchase will be stored in a table (say credits, and purchases respectively).

What i wanted to know is while the user is in a transaction which approach should I follow (approach listed with pros and cons)

store the attributes the user selects for the items in temporary tables (something like temp_credit_purchases and temp_product_purchases) and then insert the record in the actual tables (credits and purchases)

Pros

- all the unsuccessful transactions can be deleted off and there will not be a lot of missing auto-incremented ids in the actual table

Cons

- 2 inserts and 1 select - inserts are heavier than updates (which would happen in the 2nd case)

insert the data in the actual table with a temp state

Pros

- more optimal (only 1 insert and one update)

Cons

- there would be a lot of unnecessary rows in the table which would be used sometime for querying in other user facing modules (which might make the queries slower).

Although I'm able to list the pros and cons of each approach, I'm not able to take a definitive decision. Pls help me think through this?

Answer (score 1):

I would store the data in the actual table, linked to an order which has a temp state. Periodically, the orders and linked purchases can be wiped out if they are more than X hours old and the order not been completed.

Having extra rows in an indexed table does not make the query substantially slower, and you'll be cleaning them out periodically anyway. Unless of course the fact that the order was not completed is significant and you want to keep these rows and offer metrics on them e.g. 'Product which people most frequently changed their minds about'.

Bear in mind:

- Gaps in auto incremented ids are not something that you should be
  worrying about as they are designed only to make sure your rows are
  unique and are not actually data.
- Generally, you don't want to represent a quality of an entity (order completed or not) by splitting a table of similar things in two, when you can add a field somewhere instead.